# How to update recyclerview in android?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain recyclerview with adapter that populate data from sqlite database into recyclerview. Problem is that when i delete items from RecyclerView it is not updating recyclerview.

code:-

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            String title;
            title = modelList.get(position).getNotiifcationTitle();
            notificationDBHelper.removeSingleNotification(title);
            modelList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            modelList.clear();
            //Updating ArrayList
            modelList = notificationDBHelper.getAllNotificationsData();
            swapItems(modelList);
            //Setting deleted notification count
            notificationDBHelper.insertNotificationDeleteCount(1);
        }
```

Comment: add swapItems method

Comment: mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  or call the methode which you are using to attache data to recyclerview when you perform delet operation after that load data from database again.

Answer (score 1):

call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` when you want to refresh your recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

update your adapter for last like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        String title;
        title = modelList.get(position).getNotiifcationTitle();
        notificationDBHelper.removeSingleNotification(title);
        modelList.remove(position);            
        modelList.clear();
        //Updating ArrayList
        modelList = notificationDBHelper.getAllNotificationsData();
        swapItems(modelList);
        //Setting deleted notification count
        notificationDBHelper.insertNotificationDeleteCount(1);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```